# No Application Events in the 'before ApplicationContext' phase are triggered

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to listen to the ApplicationStartingEvent (or any of the pre-ApplicationContext phase) but it looks like none of them is ever fired.

Tried to set a breakpoint in the onApplicationEvent method, tried to print the event to the standard output. none works

the listener:

```
public class MyListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent applicationEvent) {
        System.out.println("Application event " + applicationEvent);
    }
}
```

the application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication();
        springApplication.addListeners(new MyListener());
        springApplication.run(MySpringBootApplication.class, args);

    }
}
```

Expect to see some events to be printed out to the console. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `run` method that you have called is a static method. This means that the state of your `springApplication` instance, including the listener that you have added, has no effect.

You should do something like this instead:

```
SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(MySpringBootApplication.class);
springApplication.addListeners(new MyListener());
springApplication.run(args);
```